# Is there a module that simply adds an 'add more' AJAX CCK field to a node form?

Tags: forms, ajax

Drupal 7:

So I want to have this type of functionality:

The user needs to be able to add an unlimited, or up to a certain value of cck fields to the node edit form.

Basically, we want to create tutorials, and then add dynamic 'steps' via ajax. (because the amount of steps will always constantly change)

An example would be the poll module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any field to allow more than one value on the same node. But if you need some kind of a group of fields, which you want to add dynamically, then I would suggest you to have a look at the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.